# How to play an alarm in WatchOS 2 when NSTimer is asleep?

Tags: timer, nstimer, watchkit

Have a specialized timer I'm creating and have the NSTimer working fine, updating on wake, etc but can only get the haptic to play if the user has the app actually on the display.  I realize there are no background apps, but looking at various ways to schedule the alert much like the native Timer app does for its simple timer.

`NSTimer.ScheduledTimerWithTimeInterval` does not fire if asleep, looking at local notifications (note this app needs to run without the iPhone present so unclear if this is possible) and perhaps `presentAlertControllerWithTitle` is the way to go but unclear how to schedule it.

This seems like a simple/typical ask but most of the timer tutorials online and the searching I've done ignore the fact the app goes to sleep or only handles the wake events to reset the timer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

With WatchOS 3.0 you can schedule UNNotificationRequest with a specified timeInterval to get notified that time out happened.

Answer (score 0):

In watchOS 2 the only situation where your app will be launched in the background is when updating a complication. watchOS 2 doesn't offer any background modes.

watchOS 3 in the other hand extends background capabilities via Background App Refreshes (BAR) and if you're a Health&Fitness or a Mindfulness app you can start a workout session using HealthKit to continuously run on the background while your workout session is active.

Other then that the only way to accomplish what you need is via notifications. In watchOS 2 you need to use the WatchConnectivity framework to wake up your iOS app and schedule a notification on the phone (later on it will be routed to the watch if the phone is locked and the watch is being worn) or in watchOS 3 you can schedule local notifications that will only be presented on the watch via the UserNotifications.framework.

For more info, please check:

[What's New in watchOS 3 (video)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/208/)

[Introduction to Notifications (video)](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/707/)

[Watch Connectivity API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/watchconnectivity)

[HKWorkoutSession API](https://developer.apple.com/reference/healthkit/hkworkoutsession)

[UNNotifications API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/usernotifications/unnotification)